# Dualboot Windows 10 and Linux on software RAID with common devices

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, raid, software-raid

I'm interested in improving the reliability and availability of the operating systems on my workstation as part of an upgrade being planned soon to my hardware. I tried to find a question like this on the net but was unsuccessful.

What I'd like to achieve is the use of software RAID to provide a mirror set for each operating system to be installed on. I know this would work with just a Linux OS, but where my knowledge breaks down is with Windows. If I went through with this, would I be able to do the traditional path of having GRUB chainload the Windows boot loader?

This is what I envision the RAID layout to look like:

```
Windows RAID
  - Partition 1 on SSD 1
  - Partition 1 on SSD 2
/dev/mapper/linux
  - /dev/sda2 on SSD 1
  - /dev/sdb2 on SSD 2
```

I understand that this would result in Linux not being able to assemble the Windows RAID set. Is this dual boot scheme tenable otherwise, though? Will I need to do anything special as far as order of installations or boot loader configurations? Any information that might assist would be most appreciated!

Comment: I suggest installing the most-often-used OS normally (on top of software RAID is fine), and using a VM for the less-often-used OS.  When I dual-booted, I always found myself wanting to run a program in the other OS, and had to hibernate the one OS to get to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this flat out isn't a supported configuration with Windows 10. The installer simply doesn't have the option to create a RAID array to place the operating system onto.